# Unable to execute update query in mongoDb using CRUD Repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

**Problem**

Unable to execute update query in mongoDb using MongoDb CRUD Repository

For Ex in MySql I can apply query like set a=x,b=y where username=p;

**Task I did for Mongo**

1)For Updating Records I have made a rest API.

2)
I am making sure that user name in unique.

```
    @PutMapping(value = "")
ApiResponse<Employee> put(@RequestBody  Employee employee) {
    if(employee.getEmail()!=null && !checkEmailValidation(employee))
        return ApiResponse.failure().message("Please enter valid email Address").build();
   else if(employee.getContact()!=null&&!checkSizeValidation(employee))
        return ApiResponse.failure().message("Min Size of Contact must be 10").object(null);
        return ApiResponse.success().object(employeeService.put(employee));
    }

@Override
public Employee put(Employee employee) {
    return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}    

public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String> {
Employee findByUsername(String userName);
Employee findByContact(String contact);
}
```

**LoginUser Model**

```
public class LoginUser {
private String contact;
private String email;
private String address;
private Gender gender;
@Indexed
private String name;
private DateTime dob;
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String username;
private String country;
private String designation;
```

**Employee Model**

```
public class Employee extends LoginUser {
@Id
private String id;
private String imageId;
```

> For the given Scenario,I am unable to apply Update Query.
>   i.e if the user enters the record and the given username already exist.

**I/P Supplied**

I have saved this user record in database First.
Now I want to update data again other than username i.e address,gender etc

{
  "address": "44 hakikat nagar"
}

**Output Expected**

Employee Records must be inserted based on username I receive

**Output Shown**

```
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException",
"message": "Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: connecto.employee index: username dup key: { : \"iouy\" }'; nested exception is com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: connecto.employee index: username dup key: { : \"iouy\" }'",
```

> Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem?Thankx in advance

Comment: Do you have the update query ? Can you add it to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram It's just save operation which updates records based on upsert logic i.e if exist update otherwise insert.I have edited the same

Comment: Do you retreive the `Employee` entity from the database with the repository before the update ?

Comment: Please take a look at the answers here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40534212/2683814. It is not possible to update specific fields using `MongoRepositoty`. Its all or none. You have to use update operators via `MongoTemplate` which will update specific fields.